# Adding custom colours to the colour picker

Tags: development, custom

[image]

Is it possible to add your own colours to the colour picker. If so how do you do so?

Comment: wich colourpicker is this

Comment: HTe one of the Ribbon for a content editor web part

Answer (score 8):

Down in the Standard Colors section you can add more colors by including styles like this:

```
<style>
.ms-rteForeColor-11 {
  color: darkred;
  -ms-name: "";
  -ms-color:"Dark Red";
}
.ms-rteForeColor-12 {
  color: darkred;
  -ms-name: "";
  -ms-color:"Dark Red";
}
</style>
```

Similar you can define new background colors using .ms-rteBakcColor-XX

The colors at the top are controlled by the theme and should not be modified by CSS

Comment: More detailed answer: http://www.bentedder.com/customizing-markup-and-table-styles-in-sharepoint-richhtmlfield/

Comment: .ms-rteBakcColor-XX is not working for me

Answer (score 1):

You can change these colors by creating a *.spcolor* file.

I think the colors you need to change are :

```
<s:color name="BodyText" value="444444" />
<s:color name="SubtleBodyText" value="75787B" />
<s:color name="StrongBodyText" value="000000" />
<s:color name="DisabledText" value="B1B1B1" />
<s:color name="ContentAccent1" value="a41128" />
<s:color name="ContentAccent2" value="00A9E0" />
<s:color name="ContentAccent3" value="84BD09" />
<s:color name="ContentAccent4" value="E31C79" />
<s:color name="ContentAccent5" value="E8772B" />
<s:color name="ContentAccent6" value="FFC72C" />
```

You can start from a standard *.spcolor* file located in "*/_catalogs/theme/15*".

Hope this helps

Comment: Could you please elaborate the answer? Whether it needs to be referenced or any supporting threads?